# ggplot2 - autosize chart and axis titles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have create some ggplot2 bar plots which print fine to screen.  When I print in PDF device, however, the chart and axis titles are too large - they sometimes extend past the left and right of the x-axis.  None of these charts have any opts() set aside from title/axis-title - its all the defaults.  What am I missing here?  Is there a way to tell ggplot to auto-size this text so that the charts look good in PDF?  Can I do this without explicitly setting opts()?

Comment: try changing the `pointsize` parameter in `pdf()`. this sometimes works.

Comment: I think that's the same as par(ps=... ).  I tried pointsize in pdf() and the plots don't change.  Strangely, its using 14 point size where my ps/pointsize is 12.  Not sure how it determines 14

Comment: I think the 14 is the result of the default theme which I think multiplies the base font size by 1.2.  It seems that I could fix this with the right theme, but I'd have to detect the size of the plotting region and the text itself to determine the parameters for the theme...was hoping for something out-of-the-box

Comment: Depending on your use, you could also use the height and width parameters of `pdf` to make the canvas bigger

Comment: Thanks.  I'm writing to a standard PDF size for printing, so I don't think that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to create a function to create a theme (like theme_bw()) and give it enough parameters so that its smart about sizing.  Will keep this post open for a few days to see if there are any other clever ideas

Comment: sorry for digging this back up, but was wondering if you could provide an example to how one could use the theme_bw() to auto size? Thanks

Comment: Its not possible to use theme_bw to autosize.  The parameters are base_size and base_family.  That's not enough context.  In the least you need the size of the area that the chart will occupy on the page.  So you could create a function `theme_bw_autosize` with that parameter.  Then you'd do a bunch of sizing math to populate the theme options such as `size` in `strip.text.x`.  The best algorithm would require the plot itself.  Then function could query the plot for various text elements and do better sizing math.  All-in-all tough stuff.